# Application.js placement - Rails 3 & jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, select, onchange

I'm dabbling with jQuery for the first time on my first Rails (3) project. I'm having trouble getting a select statement's onChange to fire when my application.js include is in the header.

This is my current set-up:

**Header includes:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

**application.js**

```
jQuery('#location_country_code').change(function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

My problem is that I can only get the onChange function to fire if I place the application.js include at the bottom of the page (ie: after the select element). It appears that placing it in the header means the event handler is not set as the element is not yet defined.

All tutorials on this type of thing talk about putting the js code in application.js so I'm assuming that I'm missing something fundamental.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should encapsulate your jQuery in a "document ready" block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#location_country_code').change(function() {
        alert('hi');
    }); 
});
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$( function() {
    jQuery('#location_country_code').change(function() {
        alert('hi');
    }); 
});
```

This waits for your document to be loaded before assigning the handler.  Otherwise, your select does not exist yet and the handler is not applied.

Alternatively, you could use a `live` call instead:

```
 jQuery('#location_country_code').live('change', function() {
     alert('hi');
 });
```

The `live` function applies the handler to the window and handles the event when it bubbles up from the select.  Because of this, the select element does not need to exist before you apply it.  This is helpful when you create elements dynamically, but want existing handlers to apply to them when they are created.  As a result, this cures the issue with elements not existing before the page is fully loaded.

**However**, it is good practice to wrap your code in a "ready" block in any case, to avoid unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

its because the code needs to be called when the element exists in the DOM. Change it to this, and it should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#location_country_code').change(function() {
    alert('hi');
  }); 
});
```

The document.ready is called after all the html and javascript files load on the page. It's also before images are called. Instead of $(document).ready(function() {});, you can also use the shortcut $(function() {});

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I'll go and do some jQuery tutorials :) Sorry, had to switch the accepted answer to Jeff. Didn't see his answer at first. I'll vote yours up.